# Empty record returned with this query when querying Oracle database with .NET but gave rows in SQL+

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oracle11g

The code below returns an empty records but gave records from SQL+.

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client");
DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();

connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=Simplex-IT-02)(PORT=1521)))
                     (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=Simplex))); User Id=User_Test;Password=password;";

DataTable table = new DataTable();

DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "SELECT text FROM user_views WHERE (view_name='ACCOUNT_BALANCES_BY_PERIOD');";

DbDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

table.Load(dataReader);
dataReader.Close();
```

Meanwhile, when I replaced the command.CommandText with "SELECT DISTINCT view_name FROM user_views" it gave me list of all available views for the given schema.

Why can't I get the sql text of a given view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `;` at the end of the query. Remove it and it should return values.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT text FROM user_views WHERE
    (view_name='ACCOUNT_BALANCES_BY_PERIOD')";
```